# MySQL update null values where product code has value

Tags: mysql

I have this query here:

```
select * from warehouselog where productDescription is null;
```

It returns me this:

```
ProductCode     productDescription
PKFIL11014      null
PKOUT15012      null
PKLAB14016      null
PKLAB14005      null
PKPOL17024      null
```

I know there is data out there with these product codes with some data in the same table.

e.g.

```
PKLAB14005      blue pen
PKPOL17024      black pen
```

How can I update the table where `productDescription is null` and set `productDescription` to a value where the `ProductCode` has data? It doesn't need to be unique.

Comment: Thorsten Kettner has the right answer. I would frame challenge though and ask why you are putting both the product id and the product description in the log table

Comment: @Kevin This is an intake log, originally was manually inputted in Excel. Data was all over the place and inputted incorrectly. I found a way to automate intake log without missing any manual data. I am trying to clean up the old data now and transfer it back into Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery, assigning the minimum or maximum value found for the product. It doesn't matter whether you choose `MIN` or `MAX`, both will look for a value that is not null. Here is an example with `MIN`:

```
update warehouselog w
set productdescription =
(
  select min(productdescription)
  from (select * from warehouselog) w2
  where w2.productcode = w.productcode
)
where productdescription is null;
```

(`from (select * from warehouselog) w2` instead of a mere `from warehouselog w2` is necessary in MySQL, because it doesn't allo the updated table to be used directly in a subquery.)

Comment: Does the `w.productcode` specifically looks for `where productdescription is null;`. I am kinda confused how it looks for the `null` value. But it worked! :D

Comment: No, `MIN` and `MAX` ignore nulls. If a product has these descriptions: 'blue pen', null, 'pen', then `MIN(productdescription)` will return 'blue pen' and `MAX(productdescription)` will return 'pen'. You only get null, when all the product's descriptions are null.

Comment: That is a very useful answer!